# zurb-foundation tabs with 'next button'

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation

I am working on a 3 step form and need to be able to have the 'next step' buttons move to the next tab (while changing the primary tab at top accordingly).Any ideas on how to setup the javascript for this? There is no documentation on this and I have been able to have the content change but not have the primary tab change at the same time.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/tabs.php

Example:

```
<dl class="tabs">
  <dd class="active"><a href="#simple1">Step 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">Step 2</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple3">Step 3</a></dd>
</dl>
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li class="active" id="simple1Tab">
    <p>Step 1</p>
    <a class="button" href="#simple2">Next Step »</a>
  </li>
  <li id="simple2Tab">
    <p>Step 2</p>
    <a class="button" href="#simple3">Next Step »</a>
  </li>
  <li id="simple3Tab">
    <p>Step 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

there might be a better way to do this... but i m just using the following as a workaround...

```
$('#formnextbutton').click(function () {  $("#tabbutton").click() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not much better but it's more dynamic.

```
$(".tabs .active + dd > a").click()
```